# Run Heroku CLI command from a java application hosted on Heroku

Tags: java, heroku

I'm looking for a way to run Heroku CLI commands within a java application hosted on Heroku.

I'd like to be able to run commands like `heroku pg:backup` `heroku pg:restore` etc

Is there a way to do that ?

---

**EDIT :** I added the Heroku CLI to my app, now I'm looking for a way to invoke heroku commands from my java code.

Maybe you could use something like this :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/path/to/herokuCLI", "myCommand");
```

Problem is I don't know how to find the right path.

If you look at the file structure of your app on Heroku you can only find your .war + some "configuration files" which is quite normal as you only push a war to Heroku : `Procfile  system.properties  target`

Besides I don't think that's the right way to do that.
I'd like to avoid doing backup/restore operations in pure java code.
Maybe you can't rely on Heroku cmd to do the job for you after all.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add the [Heroku CLI buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-cli) to your application. You can do so with: `heroku buildpacks:add heroku-community/cli`

Push a new build after you've done so and you'll now be able to run CLI commands from inside your application dynos. You can see some additional information about this in the [documentation](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-cli).